# Calling Oracle Stored Procedure throws Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I am calling this Oracle Stored Procedure using Spring SimpleJdbcCall
The code is throwing ***"Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111"***

```
        org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; 
        uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call O_XEROX_PRNT_PRT(?, ?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type: 1111; 
        nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111
```

Here is the stored Procedure, I tried to simplify it as much as I can for testing. so Its doing nothing but randomizing some values and returning random message,

The Stored Procedure is executing fine from SqlDeveloper...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE O_XEROX_PRNT_PRT 
(
CLIENT_KEY          IN VARCHAR2
,P_STATUS           IN VARCHAR2

-- OUTPUT back to java
, O_STATUS          OUT BOOLEAN
, O_MESSAGE         OUT VARCHAR2

) AS 
    PROC_STATUS         BOOLEAN;
    PROC_ERROR_MESSAGE  VARCHAR2(4000);

    rand_num number;
BEGIN

    dbms_output.put_line('O_XEROX_PRNT_PRT ');
    select round(dbms_random.value(1,10)) into rand_num     from dual;   

    IF rand_num > 8 THEN
            PROC_STATUS  := TRUE;
            PROC_ERROR_MESSAGE := 'ALL IS GOOD';
    ELSE
            PROC_STATUS  := FALSE;
            PROC_ERROR_MESSAGE := 'SOMTHING WENT WRONG!!! ';
    END IF;


END O_XEROX_PRNT_PRT;
```

Java code I am using:

```
     String CLIENT_KEY          = 'CLIENT_KEY val';
            String P_STATUS         = 'Printer works';

            Boolean O_STATUS =true;
            String O_MESSAGE ;

            JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(printerHubPortalDS);

            SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(template).withProcedureName("O_XEROX_PRNT_PRT")
                    .declareParameters(
                            new SqlParameter(CONST_CLIENT_KEY, Types.VARCHAR),
                            new SqlParameter(CONST_P_STATUS , Types.VARCHAR),                           
                            );

            MapSqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue(CONST_CLIENT_KEY,CLIENT_KEY)
                    .addValue(CONST_P_STATUS ,P_STATUS );

            //This line is throwing the error
            Map<String, Object> resultMap = jdbcCall.execute(paramMap);

            String tmp =  (String)resultMap.get(CONST_O_STATUS);
            O_STATUS = Boolean.valueOf(tmp);
            O_MESSAGE = (String) resultMap.get(CONST_O_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't defined the output parameters in the `declaredParameters`.

Adding the following under the current `SqlParameter` should solve the error.

```
new SqlOutParameter("O_STATUS", Types.BOOLEAN),
new SqlOutParameter("O_MESSAGE", Types.VARCHAR)
```

Comment: hmm, after adding that im getting Invalid column type: 16      ill google this.